# VSCode's Auto Attach is not toggling for Node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I use WSL to start VSCode with `code .` from my project directory in Windows Terminal. When VSCode starts up, "Auto Attach: Off" is shown in the status bar:

[image]

Clicking "Auto Attach: Off" in the status bar does not toggle it.

I then start my project in VSCode's integrated terminal with `npm run debug`, which corresponds to the following `scripts` line in `package.json`:

```js
"scripts": {
  "debug": "NODE_ENV=development DEBUG='knex:*' nodemon --inspect ./server.js"
}
```

However, the debugger is not auto-attached, so I need to manually run the `Attach` configuration from the *Run* panel shown on the left here:

[image]

The debugger works, but I still cannot toggle the `Auto Attach: Off` to be ***On*** instead:

[image]

Even if I **Ctrl+Shift+P** --> `Debug: Toggle Auto Attach`, nothing happens. Even if I restart VSCode after doing so.

---

So, in conclusion, how can I start my VSCode with `code .` from Windows Terminal and then just type `npm run debug` and have VSCode, run my program AND auto-attach the debugger? I also need the server to restart upon file changes, which is why I am using `nodedemon` in the `npm run debug` script.

Do I need to either:

- change `launch.json` configuration? Though I have tried essentially all of the boilerplate `launch.json` configs shown in VSCode, but none worked.
- or modify my `package.json` defined `script` for `debug`?
- or correct some setting on VSCode?

Comment: you got the solution?

Comment: @SunilGarg I filed a bug report in the github issue tracker https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102240 and the issue was resolved on their end in one of their subsequent VSCode updates. So everything works fine now without me having to have done anything. After updating to the recent version of VSCode, you may have to toggle Auto-attach off/on in the settings (restarting VSCode in between each toggle).

Comment: i cant even find the auto attach setting in the settings json autocomplete...